# GroupBy with LinqTS(Typescript)

Tags: typescript, linq, group-by, linq.js

I am using LINQTS to have some information from via grouping some data.

```
 const registered_users_data = listData
  .groupBy(
    b => moment(b.created_at).format('YYYY/MM')
  )
  .select(x => {
    x.key, x.value.count();
  })
  .toArray();
```

For above code I am getting below response highlighted in red area

[image]

If I change the code to below

```
listData
  .groupBy(b => moment(b.created_at).format('YYYY/MM'))
  .select(x => x.value.count())
  .toArray();
```

then I get below result

[image]

I want to have both key and value count in response. Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong in above code where I am getting null in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly brackets in `x => { x.key, x.value.count(); }` doesn't create an object when used in an arrow function because they are used to create a sequence of statements which should end with a `return` (if no `return` is provided, the value will be null, as in your case). What you can do is wrap the object in parantheses. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)

So this is what the code should look like:

```
const registered_users_data = listData
  .groupBy(
    b => moment(b.created_at).format('YYYY/MM')
  )
  .select(x => ({
    key: x.key,
    value: x.value.count();
  }))
  .toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Thanks for clearing the concept as well. God Bless You and Stay Safe.

Comment: @ManojSethi No problem! Thank you, you stay safe as well